# analog error pcb

Tags: pcb, analog

I am building a scale with a load cell and a INA122 equivalent circuit. When I build it in a breadboard I get very good readings but when I place it on the PCB I only get a -3.8V at the output of the INA122.

The circuit consists of an amplification stage with an equivalent circuit of the INA122, an inverter and a low-pass filter at the end.[image: Load Cell Amplification][image: Load Cell Filtering][image: Load Cell PCB]

Comment: You inspected the PCB for shorts and breaks?

Comment: Also missing parts, hot parts, reverse voltages e.t.c. It can be anything.

Comment: Is -3.8V the result when you leave the inputs floating or have you shorted them together & grounded them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're bumping into an input common-mode voltage limit which is described on page 8 of the INA122 datasheet and certainly applies to your INA122-equivalent circuit.

The problem with that configuration is that for certain combinations of gain and input common-mode voltage, A2 (your U1b) is being expected to produce an output voltage that is greater than its supply voltage.

If your load cell can handle a 10V excitation supply, then try connecting it between your Vcc and -5V.  It will then produce a common-mode voltage close to 0V instead of the 2.5-ish its probably currently giving and this should keep things within acceptable ranges for this circuit.

Comment: This, if your load cell can't handle 10V, add a series resistor between both +/-5V and the load cell. It will cost some senstivity, so more gain will likely be required.